# Integration testing using @SpringApplicationConfiguration with mocks not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, spring-boot, junit, mockito, integration-testing

There is something weird going on with my integration test when it runs in Jenkins, it fails to wire primary beans which are mocks.

However, when run locally using Maven install, it works flawlessly. This is my integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {App.class, SampleIT.class})
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port:0"})
public class SampleIT {

    @Primary
    @Bean    
    public SampleRepository sampleRepository() { //this is wired fine in my local Maven, but not in Jenkins...
        return Mockito.mock(Sample.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething {
        //when this is executed, the mock has been wired at this point in my local Maven
        //however in Jenkins, it still uses the real SampleRepositoryImpl, not the mock
    }
}
```

This the App.class, which is a Spring Boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan("com.sample")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample")
@EntityScan("com.sample")
@DependsOn("OAuth2Config")
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

I can certainly see that Jenkins is using the real SampleRepositoryImpl instead of the mock, because of the generated sql statements in the Jenkins console. Unlike in my local Maven, there are no generate sqls since it is using the mock.

Has anyone else experience this?

How to solve this issue, so that running in Jenkins will also use the mock, which is marked as primary bean?

**--------- UPDATE ---------**

If I:

1. remove SampleIT.class from @SpringApplicationConfiguration
2. and add @Configuration to the SampleIT

it works, mocks are wired. HOWEVER, this becomes a global config and my other integration tests starts picking up the mocks defined in this class. So its not really a solution, any ideas why @SpringApplicationConfiguration  does not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

What is the way you are executing the Junit in local?
You can try out executing as Maven Test and share the results.
Use @MockBean instead of @Bean and @Primary.

Comment: Still at spring-boot 1.3 thus no @MockBean yet. I am using mvn install to execute the junit in my local.

Comment: You can try Maven Test and it should reflect the same result as of Jenkins.
I have also faced the same issue in My project where Boot was creating referring to original repository. So i have  annoted class with 
         '@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
         @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)'
and for repo
        ' @Mock
 MyRepository myRepository;'
        
You can try above option.

Comment: Thanks, however the @SpringBootTest is only available in Spring Boot 1.4, our project has not yet upgraded to 1.4 yet.